# making a merge in pandas ojn 2 dataframe on multiple key

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, left-join

I have df1 and df2 and i wanna make a left join using pandas,

i also tryed this:

```
data_2 = pd.merge(df1, df2, ['var1' , 'var2' , 'var3'   ] )
```

but is not really what i want to do.

i write the following join in SQL just to show what i really wanna do (please notice that the two df has different column name):

```
create df3 as 
select a.* , b.*
from df1 as a left join df2 as b
on a.id=b.id_var
and a.speciality=b.speciality
and upcase(a.global_name)= upcase(b.product_name)
```

how can i do it using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalent:

```
(df1.assign(upcase=df1.global_name.str.upper())
    .merge(df2.assign(upcase=df2.product_name.str.upper()),
           left_on=['id', 'speciality', 'upcase'],
           right_on=['id_var', 'speciality', 'upcase'],
           how='left')
    .drop('upcase', axis=1)
)
```